# Pasar de String a Float (Leer bien)

Tags: java, string, conversión-de-tipos, split, float

Buenas amigos, necestiso pasar una cadena string a float en **JAVA**. El problema es que al final, cada string termina con unidades (volt, %, cm, m.. etc)

ejemplo: 
Convertir el **String** "0.22V" al **float**: 0.22

Muchas gracias!

PD: Todos los String que quiero transformar están a la izquierda y sus unidades correspondientes a la derecha. 
No es factible hacer split a cada uno, puesto que sería poco eficiente ya que los +30 datos están en una colección en la que debo iterar.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: No todos los datos de la colección contienen voltaje, pueden haber: %, m, mPa, V, Cº... etc.. (Solo quiero tomar el float de la izquierda)

Comment: No has expresado a que problemas te enfrentas. Tal como está escrita tu publicación, podría interpretarse que estás solicitando que hagan tu trabajo y asi no funciona esta comunidad. Te aconsejo que incluyas en tu publicación, si es posible, un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Sin un  ejemplo claro de tus datos, imposible darte una solucion.

Comment: Se malinterpretó la pregunta. Gracias toledano por tu valiosa ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente método el cual extrae de la cadena el número decimal y lo guarda en una nueva cadena, finalmente la convierte a float cuando ya ha encontrado todos los números.

```
public float stringToFloat(String string){
    String newString="";
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
        ///Este if extrae digitos del 0 al 9 y el punto.
        if(string.charAt(i)>=48 && 
        string.charAt(i)<=57 || 
        string.charAt(i)=='.'){
        newString+=string.charAt(i);
        }
        ///se termina el ciclo cuando encuentra el primer carácter no válido, ejemplos la V de volts.
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return Float.parseFloat(newString);  ///Finalmente convierte la nueva cadena a float.
}
```